# How to add password on onStop() activity android

Tags: android

I developed an application, especially for Exam, this app disallows students to use the back button (will clear its data and cache) and the Recent App button also disabled, but this app has a weakness: Students still can open another application (e.g Browsing) when they click the Home button.
Do you have any idea how to trigger a **password** when student pressed the Home button?

Here's my onStop() code :

```
@Override
protected void onStop(){
super.onStop();
this.finish();
clearApplicationData();
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: I'd rethink your entire approach.  If you're worried about them cheating, there's a simple answer for them-  use another device to cheat on.  Unless this is happening in class on locked down hardware, in which case the answer is to use paper and pencil.  And you can't launch a UI from onStop, you're stopped.  You could at best set a flag that can be checked next time onStart is called.

Comment: Yeah I know it, in my school students disallow to bring other devices, and I see an app which can do that but it's made by someone else (paid), school only counting on me to develop an app like that. Do you know the code?

Comment: Well there are many free app locker apps are available then why you need to pay and create another app .. just install it in device and set lock to required apps ..

Comment: Are the devices provided by the school? If yes, then [kiosk/lock task mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode) sound like what you want

Comment: Ahh... thanks Sergei, you help me well.. I found my solution...